# Inserting Data in Test With Annotation (See All Data=TRUE)

Tags: annotations

If I insert data in my test with (SeeAllData=True) will the data I create in the test remain in the org after the test?

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, The documentation does not say anything about what happens to data created in the test with that annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Seeing all data doesn't mean that you can modify that data outside of test context or persist new data outside of test context. You are not able to do either of those things.

However, there are very, very few situations when it is acceptable to use `seeAllData=true` on new unit tests in 2018. Unit tests should *always* create their own test data, ideally in an `@testSetup` method, and should not have any dependency upon the data present in the real organization or sandbox.

Using `seeAllData=true` makes unit tests fragile and unreliable. I spent a big chunk of today, as it so happens, debugging a very old test using `seeAllData=true` that randomly decided to start failing in production, simply because of a small and seemingly innocuous data change.

Comment: As I was writing a test as well for an older uncovered class and one of the methods is using the connectAPI, so my hand was kind of forced to use it from what I read about it online. Do you have any suggestions on how to get around this?

Comment: Hah, that is actually one of the very few cases I was referring to. The best way to handle it is probably by using dependency injection so that the class being tested doesn't actually call the Connect API in test context.